# specific citation style using multibib

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, multibib

I am using `multibib` with two bib-files. For the first one I use a numeric citation style. But for the second one I want to have [A1, A2, ...]. This works for my reference list but in my citation I still have [1, 2, ...]. How can I change this to [A1, A2,...]?

Here is my minimal document (you have to use 2 bibfiles: litA and litB)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,titlepage,parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{textcomp} %\textmu einfügen z.B.
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}     %text unterstreichen, durchstreichen usw.
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{lita}{References1}
\newcites{ownb}{References2}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\makeatletter\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{[#1]}\makeatother
\bibliographystylelita{plain}
\bibliographylita{./literature/litA}                   
\citelitd{label1}

\makeatletter\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{[A\,#1]}\makeatother
\bibliographystylelitb{plain}
\bibliographylitb{./literature/litB}                 

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 4):

`multibib` doesn't remove the ordinary citing mechanisms, merely adds additional commands to them.  Thus for the bibliography items that should not have label prefixes you can use an ordinary `\cite` command, combined with usual `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography`, and simultaneously you can use `multibib` with the `[labeled]` option to set up another cite style `\citeA` with prefix `A` and with `\bibliographystyleA` and `\bibliographyA`.  Note the prefix is constrained to be the same as the extension to the name of these commands.  Here is a cut-down example:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}

\newcites{A}{References2}

\begin{document}
Reference without prefix \cite{bb} and a reference with prefix \citeA{aa}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{lit}                 

\bibliographystyleA{plain}
\bibliographyA{lit}                   

\end{document}
```

with `lit.bib` containing

```
@Article{aa,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {Title},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2000
}

@Article{bb,
  author =   {Brother, B.},
  title =    {Titling},
  journal =  {Ann. J.},
  year =     2002
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this information. My problem is that I need several bibliographies (one per chapter), each starting with [A1]. Is this possible?

Comment: That is a rather different question, and should perhaps be asked as such.  `chapterbib` will mostly likely be able to do that for you; its `\citeform` command will allow adjusting the style of citations.