# Multibib compiling multiple .aux files

Tags: subdividing, multibib

I'm trying to run quite literally this exact example:
[specific citation style using multibib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99440/specific-citation-style-using-multibib)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}

\newcites{A}{References2}

\begin{document}
Reference without prefix \cite{bb} and a reference with prefix \citeA{aa}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{lit}                 

\bibliographystyleA{plain}
\bibliographyA{lit}                   

\end{document}
```

with lit.bib containing

```
@Article{aa,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {Title},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2000
}

@Article{bb,
  author =   {Brother, B.},
  title =    {Titling},
  journal =  {Ann. J.},
  year =     2002
}
```

And it is giving me a [?] instead of the A1 reference. Any ideas?

I have compiled using the sequence:

```
PDFLaTeX
BibTeX
PDFLaTeX
PDFLaTeX
```

Comment: You have to run also `bibtex A`

Comment: what's bibtex A?

Comment: With `multibib` active, the command `\newcites{A}{Title}` makes LaTeX produce also a file called `A.aux` (I suggest a better name than `A`). That file contains the citation commands pertaining to the secondary bibliography and you have to run BibTeX also on that file.

Comment: is there a way I can modify the Bibtex command to automatically do this each time? Currently it is: `bibtex %.aux`.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: Bibtex command in Texmaker Ubuntu 12.04. By is there a way I mean in the configure texmaker options should I be changing the Bibtex command to differ from `bibtex %.aux`

Comment: I can make user profiles to manually run bibtex %.aux but is there any way to chain the bibtex command to multiple .aux files? Can I do some means of chaining via |?

Comment: In this specific case, I don't think it's as simple as that. Instead use a automated compilation tools like latexmk or arara. LaTeXmk is configured in Texmaker by `Configure texmaker`-->`Quick Build`-->`LaTeXMK+View PDF` and it should automate and resolve the number of runs required for bibtex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `\newcitesA{References2}` is processed, LaTeX opens a new auxiliary file called `A.aux`, where it will store the citation keys pertaining to the secondary bibliography.

So, if you document is named `paper.tex`, you need to do the following sequence of commands in order to get the whole job done:

```
pdflatex paper
bibtex paper
bibtex A
pdflatex paper
pdflatex paper
```

Persuading your frontend (Texmaker) into doing also the supplementary step is quite hairy. The simplest thing is to run the third step from a terminal.

If you have a fairly recent TeX Live distribution (not the outdated TeX Live 2009 that comes with Ubuntu 12), you can use arara; just add some directives at the top of your main LaTeX file like below:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: bibtex: { files: [ A ] }
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}

\newcites{A}{References2}

\begin{document}
Reference without prefix \cite{bb} and a reference with prefix \citeA{aa}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{lit}

\bibliographystyleA{plain}
\bibliographyA{lit}

\end{document}
```

and tell Texmaker to use arara for compiling your document, see [Integration of arara in Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/integration-of-arara-in-texmaker)