# latex .aux file

Tags: bibliographies, texshop, auxiliary-files

I use TexShop.
I read this: [Two Bibliographies: one for main text and one for appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98660/two-bibliographies-one-for-main-text-and-one-for-appendix)

I have the same problem.
But I don't understand how i can to do.
How compile the sequence?

- PDFLaTeX
- BibTeX
- PDFLaTeX
- PDFLaTeX

or

- pdflatex
- bibtex .aux
- bibtex latex.aux
- pdflatex

But the my problem is how compile the file `.aux.`
You can see the pictures posted below.
I can't compile `.aux` because I can't to do click.
(disabled `typeset` button)
How run `file.aux`?

[image]

Thank you very much!
I read too:
[Multibib compiling multiple .aux files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154486/multibib-compiling-multiple-aux-files)

Comment: At the top of you file place the line `% !TEX TS–program = pdflatexmk` and then typeset your file using Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T). Then all the steps necessary will be run automatically.

Comment: Added line at the first line, cmd+T, and after which steps?

Comment: after, I tried: cmd+shift+B, cmd+T, cmd+T. But I not obtained the result, because I think I left out the command of file .aux, that I didn't understand too. Help me to understand. Thank you. What I forgot?

Comment: Doing that in TeXShop runs the pdflatexmk engine which will automatically run pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex and pdflatex on the correct files.

Comment: Sorry! The result should come out, but I get only one bibliography instead of two. I don't understand.

Comment: I don't understand because, when I click (cmd+shift+B), the software considers only a bibliography!!!  How do I run both two bibliography files?

Comment: Please give a minimum example to demonstrate how you are using multibib. If you are ding it correctly the pdflatexmk engine should do all the right processing. Do you have multiple sux files?

Comment: software: Texshop; 
file: a1.tex: % 
!TEX TS–program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}

\newcites{A}{References2}

\begin{document}
Reference without prefix \cite{bb} and a reference with prefix \citeA{aa}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{lit}                 

\bibliographystyleA{plain}
\bibliographyA{lit}                   

\end{document} ;

Comment: file lit.bib: 
@Article{aa,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {Title},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2000
}

@Article{bb,
  author =   {Brother, B.},
  title =    {Titling},
  journal =  {Ann. J.},
  year =     2002
} ; 
now I pressed the keys (cmd+t) and I got these files: 
A.aux
a1.aux
a1.log
a1.pdf
a1.synctex.gz 
and a1.pdf shows this: 
Reference without prefix [?] and a reference with prefix [?]. ; 
now I pressed the keys (cmd+shift+b) and I got these files: 
a1.bbl
a1.blg ;

Comment: and in the 'console', it shows this results: 
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (Web2C 7.5.7)
The top-level auxiliary file: a1.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: lit.bib
now I pressed the keys (cmd+t) and I got these files: 
A.aux
a1.aux
a1.log
a1.pdf
a1.synctex.gz
and a1.pdf shows this: 
Reference without prefix [1] and a reference with prefix [?]. References
[1] B. Brother. Titling. Ann. J., 2002.

Comment: now I pressed again the keys (cmd+t) and I got in a1.pdf the same text: 
Reference without prefix [1] and a reference with prefix [?]. References
[1] B. Brother. Titling. Ann. J., 2002.
Now, why is this left: '?'. What can I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With the lit.bib file containing

```
@Article{aa,
author = {Author, A.},
title = {Title},
journal = {Journal},
year = 2000 }
@Article{bb,
author = {Brother, B.},
title = {Titling},
journal = {Ann. J.},
year = 2002 }
```

and test.tex containing

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{A}{References2}
\begin{document}
Reference without prefix \cite{bb} and a reference with prefix \citeA{aa}. 
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{lit}
\bibliographystyleA{plain}
\bibliographyA{lit}
\end{document}
```

both in the same directory I run Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T) and I get a complete document with all citations and and bibliographies present. The Console shows the runs of pdflatex, bibtex, etc.

How old is your TeX distribution and what is your version of TeXShop?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64907/discussion-on-answer-by-herb-schulz-latex-aux-file).