# customise bibliography style of multi bibliography

Tags: multibib

I have two bibliographies in my document. I am using multi bib. I displayed the two bibliographies in two separate list using the following code. But I need to customise the citations of one of them to be [S1] and the other one to be numeric citaton [1]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex: { files: [ mydoc, PS ] }
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{PS}{Primary Studies}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}
\section{Main body text}

reference 1 [1]
primary study 1 [S1]


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{template_latex_bibliography-bib}

\begin{appendices}
\section{List of Primary studies}
\bibliographystylePS{IEEEtran}
\bibliographyPS{mydoc-primarystudies-bib}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would this be of any help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102262/117534

Comment: This worked in the references list when using the alpha style only, but not in the in-text citation.. any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show what you have done (i.e. the code and output)? (and provide some dummy bib entries as well so it is easier for us to test) It seems to work as expected for me, but I may be misunderstanding your question..

Comment: working with the IEEEtran style now.. thanks